# Iphone app - Why does my iPhone app not get rounded corners?

Tags: iphone, xcode, jailbreak

I made a little app that does nothing to see if I could put an icon.
The icon appear on my iphone, but it does not have rounded corners like every other app.

I read someone saying it doesn't work for jailbroken apps?
But cydia etc has rounded corners?

The way I put them on my iPhone is I use a fake Code signing and then I take the .app and SSH into my iPhone.

How can I get rounded corners?

Comment: Could you elaborate? Why are the corners not getting rounded?

Comment: If your problem is related to jailbreaking, you should include the `jailbreak` tag.  I fixed it this time.

Comment: I have no idea if it's related to jailbreaking or not

Comment: You're installing on a jailbroken phone using jailbreaking tools.  That's enough to warrant the `jailbreak` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're installing the app without a dev license, i.e. dropping the .app into /Applications/, then the gloss and rounded corners effect will not get applied to the icon. You'll have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can. You will need to use Xcode, though - it won't work by simply scp-ing your app into your device. Here's how:

1. Bypass code signature by selecting "Don't Code Sign" in the device target build settings
2. Get *appsync* from here http://hackulo.us/wiki/AppSync, or from the hackolo.us repo. I personally prefer installing it manually.
3. From Xcode, select the device target and hit "Run". Your app should open on your phone and you should see the glossy, round-cornered icon.

Good Luck!